# Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol when using osg-Headers in MSVS2012

Tags: c++, lnk2019, unresolved-external, openscenegraph

I'm trying to compile a example program for learning to work with osg, but the way to success seems hard as always.

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <osgDB\ReadFile>
#include <osgViewer\Viewer>

int main()
{
   osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
   viewer.setSceneData(osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg"));
   return viewer.run();
}
```

I added `C:\Program Files\OpenSceneGraph-3.2.0\include` to `Additional Include Directories`.
Furthermore I added `C:\Program Files\OpenSceneGraph-3.2.0\lib` to `Additional Library Directories` and

```
osgd.lib;
osgViewerd.lib;
osgDBd.lib;
osgFXd.lib;
osgGAd.lib;
osgUtild.lib;
%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

to `Additional Dependecies`.

Also debug-mode is chosen.

---

When trying to compile I get multiple similar errors:

```
  1>mainApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
""__declspec(dllimport) public: static class osgDB::Registry * __cdecl
osgDB::Registry::instance(bool)" (__imp_?instance@Registry@osgDB@@SAPAV12@_N@Z)"
in function ""class osg::Node * __cdecl osgDB::readNodeFile
(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)"
(?readNodeFile@osgDB@@YAPAVNode@osg@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)"

1>mainApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
""__declspec(dllimport) public: class osgDB::Options * __thiscall 
osgDB::Registry::getOptions(void)" (__imp_?getOptions@Registry@osgDB@@QAEPAVOptions@2@XZ)" in
 Funktion ""class osg::Node * __cdecl osgDB::readNodeFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" 
(?readNodeFile@osgDB@@YAPAVNode@osg@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V
?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)".

1>mainApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
 ""__declspec(dllimport) class osg::Node * __cdecl osgDB::readNodeFile(class
 std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const
 &,class osgDB::Options const *)" (__imp_?readNodeFile@osgDB@@YAPAVNode@osg@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
$allocator@D@2@@std@@PBVOptions@1@@Z)" in Funktion ""class osg::Node * __cdecl 
osgDB::readNodeFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
 std::allocator<char> > const &)" 
(?readNodeFile@osgDB@@YAPAVNode@osg@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V
?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)".

1>mainApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall osgViewer::Viewer::Viewer(void)"
 (__imp_??0Viewer@osgViewer@@QAE@XZ)" in Funktion "_main".

1>mainApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
""__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall osgViewer::Viewer::setSceneData(class 
osg::Node *)" (__imp_?setSceneData@Viewer@osgViewer@@UAEXPAVNode@osg@@@Z)" in Funktion "_main".

1>mainApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
""__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual int __thiscall osgViewer::Viewer::run(void)" 
(__imp_?run@Viewer@osgViewer@@UAEHXZ)" in Funktion "_main".

1>mainApp.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol 
""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall osgViewer::Viewer::`vbase destructor'(void)"
 (__imp_??_DViewer@osgViewer@@QAEXXZ)" in Funktion "_main".

1>C:\Users\Admin2\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\osgTest\Debug\osgTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 nicht aufgelöste Externe
```

(Sorry for some german expresions in the code, I tried to translated most of them.)

Does anybody know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know this library, but maybe a 32 bit vs 64 bit mismatch?

Comment: But how can I find out that?

Comment: First thing is are you running 64 bit Windows? If so then change your project to build for 64 bit Windows and try again.

Comment: Finally that was the solution. Shame on me. But thanks for reminding to such simple stuff.